# Why there suddenly were so many 400 request in my access log?

Tags: nginx

Below are little part of my access_log

```
118.186.8.50 - - [19/Dec/2011:22:42:57 +0800] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
05
118.186.8.50 - - [19/Dec/2011:22:42:57 +0800] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
06
118.186.8.50 - - [19/Dec/2011:22:42:57 +0800] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
07
118.186.8.50 - - [19/Dec/2011:22:42:57 +0800] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
08
118.186.8.50 - - [19/Dec/2011:22:42:57 +0800] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
09
220.173.136.39 - - [19/Dec/2011:22:43:22 +0800] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
10
220.173.136.39 - - [19/Dec/2011:22:43:22 +0800] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
11
220.173.136.39 - - [19/Dec/2011:22:43:22 +0800] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
12
220.173.136.39 - - [19/Dec/2011:22:43:22 +0800] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
13
220.173.136.39 - - [19/Dec/2011:22:43:22 +0800] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
14
220.173.136.39 - - [19/Dec/2011:22:43:22 +0800] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

And the volume was very huge, some like one hundred thousand of these 400 request per second. And I'm pretty sure there are no errors on my site in that period of time.(No error report and I didn't change the source code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone was [Fuzzing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Fuzzing) your server. Also see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing).

Basically involves sending rapid blocks of invalid data to see if anything breaks.

Nginx is set to return a 400 error error when no request data is sent.

Don't worry about it. Nginx can just keep on bouncing them forever without breaking a sweat.

Comment: The only thing he'll have to worry about is the log files absorbing disk space. This is where proper log rotation is helpful.

Comment: Same problem here. The amount of different IP addresses does not make an attack (fuzzing) very probable in my opinion. Still looking for a better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Check and see if the ip address causing the 400 is using Google Chrome. Chrome uses pre-connection to establish several connection with server, and close them if not used.

Since no request is made in the connection, nginx will record this error.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem here, and I have exactly the same log file format so I assume that the OP didn't change the default. Which means that the user agent string is being logged - it just so happens that it does not contain any value. So I'm not sure how to check whether those clients are using Chrome. I myself couldn't reproduce this error in the log using Chrome 26 just now. Any other hints?

Comment: User agent is sent as a request header, unless/until a request is made, nginx has no means to know and log the user agent string. You can, however, check other log records that came from that IP address and, if any actual request were in fact made by that client, learn whether it was Chrome or not.